# Bug (?) with numpy indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to achieve a kind of 2d filter with numpy, and I found something that looks to me like a bug.

In the example below, I'm trying to target the 2nd and 4th columns of the first, second and last lines of my data, ie:

```
[[ 2  4]
 [ 8 10]
 [26 28]]
```

I am aware that the second to last line does return that, but I wouldn't be able to assign anything there (it returns a copy). And this still doesn't explain why the last one fails.

```
import numpy as np

# create my data: 5x6 array
data = np.arange(0,30).reshape(5,6)

# mask: only keep row 1,2,and 5
mask = np.array([1,1,0,0,1])
mask = mask.astype(bool)

# this is fine
print 'data\n', data, '\n'

# this is good
print 'mask\n', mask, '\n'

# this is nice
print 'data[mask]\n', data[mask], '\n'

# this is great
print 'data[mask, 2]\n', data[mask, 2], '\n'

# this is awesome
print 'data[mask][:,[2,4]]\n', data[mask][:,[2,4]], '\n'

# this fails ??
print 'data[mask, [2,4]]\n', data[mask, [2,4]], '\n'
```

output:

```
data
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]] 

mask
[ True  True False False  True] 

data[mask]
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]] 

data[mask, 2]
[ 2  8 26] 

data[mask][:,[2,4]]
[[ 2  4]
 [ 8 10]
 [26 28]] 

data[mask, [2,4]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
```

I'm posting this here, because I'm not confident enough in my numpy skills to be sure this is a bug, and file a bug report...

Thanks for your help/feedback !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug.

This is an implementation definition

If you read [array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in section Advanced Indexing you notice that it says

> Purely integer array indexing When the index consists of as many
>   integer arrays as the array being indexed has dimensions, the indexing
>   is straight forward, but different from slicing. Advanced indexes
>   always are broadcast and iterated as one:

```
result[i_1, ..., i_M] == x[ind_1[i_1, ..., i_M], ind_2[i_1, ..., i_M],
                       ..., ind_N[i_1, ..., i_M]]
```

therefore

```
print 'data[mask, [2,4]]\n', data[mask, [1,2,4]], '\n'
```

works and outputs

```
data[mask, [1,2,4]]
[ 1  8 28]
```

index length in broadcasting must be the same

Maybe you can achieve what you want using `ix_` function. See [array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

```
columns = np.array([2, 4], dtype=np.intp)
print data[np.ix_(mask, columns)]
```

which outputs

```
[[ 2  4]
 [ 8 10]
 [26 28]]
```